# elfinder : with page when is open

Tags: php, ckeditor, elfinder

I don't understand why, but when I open elfinder by ckeditor, I have only a white pop up page. I use the last version of ckeditor.
Hhere my code than I use.

My config : elfinder.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function getUrlParam(paramName) {
    var reParam = new RegExp('(?:[\?&]|&amp;)' + paramName + '=([^&]+)', 'i') ;
    var match = window.location.search.match(reParam) ;

    return (match && match.length > 1) ? match[1] : '' ;
}

$().ready(function() {
    var funcNum = getUrlParam('CKEditorFuncNum');

    var elf = $('#elFinder').elFinder({
        url : 'php/connector.minimal.php',  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
        getFileCallback : function(file) {
            window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, file.url);
            elf.destroy();
            window.close();
        },
        resizable: false,
    }).elFinder('instance');
});
```

My config connector.minimal.php

```
    // Documentation for connector options:
// https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options
$opts = array(
  'debug' => true,
  'roots' => array(
                    array(
                      'driver'        => 'LocalFileSystem',           // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
                //      'path'          => '../../../../sources/image/',         // path to files (REQUIRED)
                //      'URL'           =>  '/boutique/sources/image/', // URL to files (REQUIRED)

                      'path'          =>  DIR_FS_CATALOG_IMAGES,         // path to files (REQUIRED)
                      'URL'           =>  DIR_WS_CATALOG_IMAGES, // URL to files (REQUIRED)  /sources/image/categories/News_image2.jpg

                      'uploadDeny'    => array('all'),                // All Mimetypes not allowed to upload
                      'uploadAllow'   => array('image', 'text/plain'),// Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` allowed to upload
                      'uploadOrder'   => array('deny', 'allow'),      // allowed Mimetype `image` and `text/plain` only
                      'accessControl' => 'access',             // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
                      //'uploadMaxSize' => '3MB',

//hide some extansions

                      'attributes' => array(
                                            array( // hide readmes
                                                    'pattern' => '/README/',
                                                    'read' => false,
                                                    'write' => false,
                                                    'hidden' => true,
                                                    'locked' => false
                                                  ),
                                            array( // restrict access to png files
                                                    'pattern' => '/\.htaccess$/',
                                                    'write' => false,
                                                    'read' => false,
                                                    'hidden' => true,
                                                  ),
                                             array( // restrict access to php files
                                                     'pattern' => '/\.php$/',
                                                     'write' => false,
                                                     'read' => false,
                                                     'hidden' => true,
                                                   ),
                                             array( // restrict access to html files
                                                     'pattern' => '/\.html$/',
                                                     'write' => false,
                                                     'read' => false,
                                                     'hidden' => true,
                                                   ),
                                             array( // restrict access to htm files
                                                     'pattern' => '/\.htm$/',
                                                     'write' => false,
                                                     'read' => false,
                                                     'hidden' => true,
                                                   ),
                                              array( // restrict access to txt files
                                                    'pattern' => '/\.txt$/',
                                                    'write' => false,
                                                    'read' => false,
                                                    'hidden' => true,
                                                  ),
                                              array( // restrict access to txt files
                                                'pattern' => '/\.zip$/',
                                                'write' => false,
                                                'read' => false,
                                                'hidden' => true,
                                              )
                                            ),
                    ),

                    array(
                      'dirMode'       => 0755,
                      'fileMode'      => 0644
                    )
                  )
);

// run elFinder
$connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
$connector->run();
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: yes, I changed little thing.
I have this messae : Invalid backend configuration.
Readable volumes not available.  
'path'          =>  /test/boutique/image         // path to files (REQUIRED)
'URL'           => /var/www/test/boutique/image, // URL to files (REQUIRED)  /marketplace/sources/image/categories/News_image2.jpg


the htaccess could be the problem ?

Comment: found a solution, I forgot something inside my setup. oups !